# SQL Update specific column on all rows in a table from another table where id matches

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

These are the 2 tables that i have in my database, first one holds a price

```
prices

appid      de      us      ru      nl      gb
29382      899     999     1299     899    699
48371     1299    1599     1899    1299    999
58193      699     899      999     899    599
```

And other table is games which stores various info about games:

```
games

appid      title      releasedate      controler      language
29382     title 1     1358197200           1             en
48371     title 2     1329858000           0             en
58193     title 3     1201554000           1             en
```

Now for an easier use it would be much better if i could have only one table with games, so i want to move column us from prices to table games but i need to match id's so the prices dont get all messed up. I created 2 columns in table games called priceus and pricediscount. Now i don't know how can i move everything from table prices and only cell us to newly created 2 cells in table games.

This is my last tryout but i can't get it working for the last 4 hours

```
    UPDATE games
    SET games.priceus = prices.us, 
        games.pricediscount = prices.us
    FROM prices
    INNER JOIN prices
    ON games.appid = prices.appid
```

But it's another fail in my tryouts.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is it that you wish to do? And what have you tried?

Comment: Not sure you asked a question here... though your subject suggests you want to use UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON ... SET table1.foo=table2.bar

Comment: Hi mate, you should edit your question to state exactly what it is you are hoping to do. At the moment you have the structure and table data, but no real question.

Comment: I have mistakenly clicked on post question before i completed writing it, im sorry i edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there with your query:

```
UPDATE games
INNER JOIN prices
ON games.appid = prices.appid
SET games.priceus = prices.us, 
    games.pricediscount = prices.us
```

Comment: Oh man i was so close... This did the trick, now prices are on their own places in cells.